# Created custom UINavigationController - using the iOS 7 swiping gesture doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So I had created a very simple custom NavigationController a couple years ago, of course it subclasses UINavigationController and the only method it overrides is

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
```

in it I show a UIAlertView asking the user to make sure they want to go back. When they select yes it goes back using

```
[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Everything is working right except for with iOS 7 when using the new swiping from left to right gesture to go back to the previous screen.
It correctly goes back to the previous screen however the top navigation bar doesn’t change.

For example if I’m on my main screen and I click on Row1. The view will change and the nav bar will display Row1 as the title and a ‘< Back’ button on the top left.

Clicking on the ‘< Back’ button works 100% as expected.

If I swipe left to right to go back, the view will go back to my main screen however the nav bar will still be showing the ‘< Back’ button and ‘Row1’ as the title.

I tried just using UINavigationController instead of my custom class which subclasses it and the swiping features work correctly so I know that’s the problem. I must be missing a call or something in my custom class

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I just edited my CustomNavigation code a bit and it now seems to work. When using the top left Back button for some reason shouldPopItem was getting called twice, so I had some code to make it work correctly with iOS 6 and lower.
When using the swipe gesture I noticed that it was only being called once and the first time I was popping the controller but returning NO (which was why the nav bar wasn't changing). I now put a check for iOS 7 and return YES right away which fixed the problem and now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

`navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` is a delegate method on UINavigationBar, which UINavigationController implements. So all you're doing is stopping the navigation bar from popping a `UINavigationItem`. That's why when you override this that it prevents the navigation bar from removing the item associated with the `UIViewController` being popped. It shouldn't actually ever prevent the navigation controller from popping a view controller, and it was probably just a side effect of the old implementation that made it work right. Either they changed something, or there's just a difference with how it works when the gesture is used, that makes this hack no longer work right. Anyway, generally you're not supposed to be able to prevent the back button from going back. If you want to present a screen that requires some kind of confirmation to go back, or a task to be completed or cancelled first, you should present a modal view controller instead. Otherwise, you could replace the default back button with your own and hide the normal back button. Then your custom button (which would look different unless you went to a lot of work) could call a custom method to prompt first.

Of course you'll want to disable the pan gesture if you stick with using a `UINavigationController`. There's a property on `UINavigationController` to get the gesture recognizer:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIGestureRecognizer *interactivePopGestureRecognizer NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

You can disable it so that it will no longer make you go back.